# Usage of 'we' by companies

Tags: grammar

Often companies refer to themselves as 'we', e.g.

> We offer the following services

Even though a company is singular, is this correct usage of 'we'?

If not, what should be the correct usage?

Comment: It is correct and common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We+as+a+company+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWe%20as%20a%20company%3B%2Cc0

Comment: How else would a company refer to itself in the first person?

Answer (score 4):

A company may be a singular entity but it is comprised of many people... some companies are two people, some are thousands, regardless, most are made up of many people.

When a company says "we", they are referring to the **people** that make up the company.

In your example, though the company may offer certain services, these services require the work of many people, so the "we" is appropriate.

Anyway, what would the other option be? I? If you're going to make a statement like this, you must use either the company name or a first-person pronoun is required. Your only options are "I" or "we"... but "I" is used exclusively to talk about oneself... so it would be confusing.

If the homepage of the company said:

> Welcome to the homepage of Company Alpha; **I** produce TVs, radios, and computers for people around the world.

This literally means that the homepage is the entity that creates TVs, radios, and computers, which doesn't make sense.

If, instead, it said "we", it makes much more sense.

Comment: According to neo-liberal orthodoxy, the company _is_ the shareholders; it cannot and must not have any other concerns than increasing shareholder value. Perhaps because this conflicts with human nature, which perceives the staff of the company, not as mere tools of the shareholders, but as a _team_ of people making a living together (mammoth hunters?), nobody wants actually to talk like this, particularly not vis-a-vis partners and customers. We want to think that we are doing business with real live _people_, not an abstraction created by stock-trading algorithms.

Comment: "Shareholders" are still "people that make up a company"...

Comment: But not ones the customer is going to meet.

Comment: Have you ever met the person who made your t-shirts over in Malaysia or wherever? No customer ever meets **most** of the people who make up a company.

Comment: The use of *WE* is just a marketing issue..no royal or whatsoever other fantasy about it!!

Comment: Of course not, but our original context was one of polite (or lucrative) fiction. And with a service company repairing something in your home or office, the company most definitely presents as a "we", named individuals, rather than an "it". Even though technically they, from the manager down, are all mute tools of Robber Baron Investments Inc.

Comment: @DavidPugh - *from the manager down, are all mute tools of Robber Baron Investments Inc.*  that why they use *WE*.

Comment: @Josh: _Nos miseri homines_, as the Grace at my college began.....

Comment: @DavidPugh - *Smile and be happy*  the Grace at my kindergarden said! :))

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying my doubt. Enjoyed reading through the exchange of comments as well!

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct usage as companies attempting to sell their items will say 'we'.
'We' sounds more friendly and and approachable to the customer.

You are right that a company is singular and are a 'thing'. When they refer 'it' to a company it would seem colder in a way. They are trying to say that they are a body of people, not some mechanized machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the majestic plural, or the royal "we".

It is quite common.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we)

[Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/the-royal-we?page=all) also lists the The Editorial We and The Political We.

The links don't specifically identify the case of the company 'we', I'll admit. But the underlying principle is the same. The 'we' is referring to the people in the entity as a whole rather than any particular individual.

The following is [dialog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzGuQ5XuRAU) from the movie Wreck-it Ralph, which uses the term in the company sense.

> "Who is 'we'?"
>
> "Candy tree department."
>
> "Oh! Where is everybody else?"
>
> "It's just me today."
>
> "So you just meant like ***the royal 'we'***?"

Comment: That article says only that this is used by people of high station, it says nothing about companies using it.

Comment: I don't think the the *majestic plural* has anything to do with *"we" referrinig to a comany*.

Comment: Given the self-image of some companies, I am entirely cool with calling it the majestic plural.

Comment: @Catija: See edit.